# Update depending on the row number SQL Server 2008

Tags: row-number

This one is kind of weird and my lack of experience has me asking this.

I have an update to do and because of how bad the tables are put together where I'm grabbing this data it makes it a bit difficult.

The scenario:
There could be 1 to x amount of Visits per Patient. I want to grab the last visit. Here is where the problem is - one patient can have two or three IDs. These IDs are linked to ONE ID to help migrate them over to a new database and under one ID.

Now I've tried top 1 in a cross apply and a joining on a maxid. I can get some of it to work but not all. So I used a row number ranking to get how many times a particular person visited. However I have to run a pass on the update for each visit to get the last one as it will overwrite the previous.

Is there a way to use row_number() over (partition by B.Uid order by B.Uid) PID

So I would run a pass where pid = 1 then another pass on where pid = 2 and so on.

I am thinking there must be a way to have it do one pass - either by setting up some while loop or checking to see the highest PID then update.